# Python script not outputting SSH command correctly

Tags: python

I have this function inside of my code -

```
def name():
     print("Connecting to  server.")
     host = '111.222.232.129'
     client.connect(host, username=username, pkey=mykey)
     for item in tenants:
          stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("""sudo -u apache grep -i "my_text" /var/www/html/wwwroot/names." + ''.join(item) + "website/myfile.txt | awk -F "'" '{ print $4}'""")

          print stdout
```

The variable that the loop is pulling from is this -

```
tenants = [ ['Kyle'],
          ['Greg'],
          ['Giles'],
          ['George'],
          ['Sebastien'],
          ['Ricardo'],
          ['Rocky'],
          ['Cartman'],
          ['Kenny'],
          ['Bobby'],
          ['Tim'],
          ['Chris'] ]
```

When running this code, the output that I get when I call the name function is -

```
Connecting to server.
<bound method ChannelFile.read of <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 1 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x941290L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>>
<bound method ChannelFile.read of <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 2 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x941290L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>>
<bound method ChannelFile.read of <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 3 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x941290L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>>
```

If I make the print statement `print stdout.read()`, I get a number of blank lines.

The output when I run this command in bash is the output that I want, so the actual command I am running is valid and returns the proper output.

How can I get the correct string to display?  How can I get the expected output from the bash command from stdout?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you have triple quotes around the whole command, the `join(item)` in the middle isn't being executed, it's just part of the shell command.

Comment: Add `echo ` to the front of the command and see what you get back.

Comment: What is the "correct" string? What is the "expected" output? We have no way to know.

Answer (score -1):

```
command = client.exec_command("""sudo -u apache grep -i "my_text" /var/www/html/wwwroot/names." + ''.join(item) + "website/myfile.txt | awk -F "'" '{ print $4}'""")

for c in command:
    print c
```

That should print the actual result. Basically loop the response.